# php index switch case issue

Tags: php, .htaccess

My .htaccess removes extensions (.html) and gives string to index.php where I have switch statement.

The switch works great except when the string starts with "index.php/"

ie. if the url is:

```
example.com/index.php/randomtext
```

the string will be:

```
index.php/randomtext
```

and it will show my index page without styling.

So how would I implement if the string starts with "index.php/" to show error page?

Is there some way like:

```
case "index.php/*":
      include ('error.html');
      break;
```

Comment: You need to break up the URL into parts before commencing with the switch case

Comment: If you've got a defined error case, just check for it first before starting the switch statement, using `strpos` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using the switch case, I would place a check before that and use a simple if/else to check for that value, since you are going to want to search part of the string.

```
$error_check = "index.php/randomtext";
$pattern = '/^(index\.php)\/.*?$/';

if( preg_match($pattern, $error_check, $match) ){
    include ('error.html');
}else{
    //switch case here
}
```

pregmatch takes 3 parameters. The first is the pattern to search for, the second is the string to search, and the third is the match array that is returned.

The ^ in the pattern anchors the search to the beginning of the string and the $ anchors the search to the end of the string. Meaning that the pattern you are looking for starts at the begging of the string and ends and the end of the string. The code inside the () is what you are searching for. The backslash is an escape character used to escape the period. Periods that are not escaped mean any character, the * means zero or more of previous expression and the ? means 0 or 1 of previous expression and forces minimal matching when the expression may match several strings within the search string.

NOTE: should be preg_match, not pregmatch

Comment: I don't know why your solution doesn't work... still get index page without style...

Comment: @johnny456 Did you test the regex part outside of the script, to make sure it is getting to the correct section in the code? What exactly is the string that contains the "index.php"?

Comment: @johnny456 Notice I changed pregmatch to preg_match

Comment: @bsbuy It works if I put it like this: '/^(index\.php\/.*)?$/' but then empty string (ie. example.com/) also shows error.html

Comment: @johnny456 You can't have .* in the (). This is what is causing the empty string to match it as well.  I tested with `$error_check = "index.php/randomtext";
$pattern = '/^(index\.php)\/.*?$/';

if( preg_match($pattern, $error_check, $match) ){
    echo "OH Yeah<br>";
}` and this does work.

Comment: @bsbuy must be something with my htaccess with cutting .html and /